# The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl: * <rootDir>\package.json * <rootDir>\sanity\package.json

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, sanity

This is my first time using sanity and I have encounter with this problem, When running `expo start` , I will be very thankful if you can help me with this

```
jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: deliveroo-clone
 The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
* <rootDir>\package.json
* <rootDir>\sanity\package.json

Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the 
console for more info
at setModule (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\jest-haste- 
map\build\index.js:576:17)
at workerReply (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\jest-haste- 
map\build\index.js:647:9)
at async Promise.all (index 10)
at C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:459:22
at Function.load (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\metro\src\node- 
haste\DependencyGraph.js:86:36)
at Bundler.ready (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo- 
clone\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:61:5)
at IncrementalBundler.ready (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo- 
clone\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:309:5)
at Server.ready (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo- 
clone\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1156:5) {
mockPath1: 'package.json',
mockPath2: 'sanity\\package.json'
}`
Unrecognized event: {"type":"transformer_load_failed","error":
```

{"mockPath1":"package.json","mockPath2":"sanity\package.json","name":"Error","message":"Duplicate
d files or mocks. Please check the console for more info","stack":"Error: Duplicated files or
mocks. Please check the console for more info\n    at
setModule (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\jest-haste-
map\build\index.js:576:17)\n    at workerReply (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-
clone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:647:9)\n    at async Promise.all (index
10)\n    at C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\jest-haste-
map\build\index.js:459:22\n    at Function.load (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-
clone\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:86:36)\n    at Bundler.ready
(C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:61:5)\n
at IncrementalBundler.ready (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-
clone\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:309:5)\n    at Server.ready
(C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1156:5)"}}
`

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: not yet. I wasted 8 days looking for answers everywhere but with no luck finding any. so i abandoned it

Comment: yeah I had to do the same

Comment: this is the only solution that I have managed to came up with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nh4go8IyEmE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with a React-native and Sanity project.

The only solution I find was create folders "server" and "client". Drag all sanity folder/files to the "server" folder and all the other files into the "client" folder.

Note: just `cd` into "client" folder to run the react-native project and cd to "server" folder to run `sanity start`.

Comment: I will try it out. And get back to you ❤️

Answer (score 7):

Go to `package.json` inside the sanity folder and change the value for the name, then save and reload the app.

Just like this, change what you have as the value of name:

```
{
  "name": "foodr-app*-sanity*",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "package.json",
  "author": "<@gmail.com>",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
}
```

Comment: Worked! :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

{
"name": use_different_name,
"private": true,
"version": "1.0.0",

Comment: put your code into the suitable tag

Answer (score 0):

This older post worked for me. It's just a matter of giving a different "name"  for one of the package.json files. The two different package.json files with the same value for the name property is the issue.
[React Native DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819565/react-native-duplicateerror-duplicated-files-or-mocks/65937626#65937626)